# AirPrint authentication using client certificate

Tags: ios, security, certificate, airprint

Is the AirPrint authentication via client certificates supported in iOS 16.1?

Bonjour specification defines an "air" key in the TXT record with a "certificate" as a valid option. We tried to import a certificate into iOS and modify our print server to negotiate the client certificate during the TLS handshake but iOS didn't provide any client certificate during the handshake.